# How to remove element from list while iterating the same list in golang

Tags: list, go, listiterator

I am new to go language. I would like to remove elements from the list while iterating the list based on a condition in go language. For example I want remove the duplicate elements from the list. Code is given below.

```
package main
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)
var sMap map[int]bool
func main() {
    l := list.New()
    l.PushFront(4)
    l.PushFront(5)
    l.PushFront(7)
    l.PushFront(6)
    l.PushFront(5)
    l.PushFront(4)
    l.PushFront(5)
    l.PushFront(7)
    l.PushBack(9)
    l = removeDuplicate(l)
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
}
func removeDuplicate(l *list.List) *list.List {
    sMap = make(map[int]bool)
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        m := e.Value.(int)
        fmt.Println("VALUE : ", m)
        if sMap[m] == true {
            fmt.Println("Deleting ", e.Value)
            l.Remove(e)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Adding New Entry", e.Value)
            sMap[m] = true
        }
    }
    return l
}
```

The above code iterates through the list only till the first removal. I am trying to remove the element while iterating through the same list. That is the reason why it is not working. Could anyone suggest an list iterator in golang?

Comment: Your code fragment is incomplete and doesn't compile. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @peterSO - I added the complete code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `e` is removed from the list then call of `e.Next()` in the next loop will return `nil`. Therefore, need to assign `e.Next()` to the `next` before deleting `e`. Here is the example to clear all elements by iterating (in [list_test.go](https://golang.org/src/container/list/list_test.go))

```
// Clear all elements by iterating
var next *Element
for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = next {
    next = e.Next()
    l.Remove(e)
}
```

Same pattern can be applied to the question as following;

```
package main
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)
var sMap map[int]bool
func main() {
    l := list.New()
    l.PushFront(4)
    l.PushFront(5)
    l.PushFront(7)
    l.PushFront(6)
    l.PushFront(5)
    l.PushFront(4)
    l.PushFront(5)
    l.PushFront(7)
    l.PushBack(9)
    l = removeDuplicate(l)
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
}
func removeDuplicate(l *list.List) *list.List {
    sMap = make(map[int]bool)
    var next *list.Element
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = next {
        m := e.Value.(int)
        next = e.Next()
        fmt.Println("VALUE : ", m)
        if sMap[m] == true {
            fmt.Println("Deleting ", e.Value)
            l.Remove(e)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Adding New Entry", e.Value)
            sMap[m] = true
        }
    }
    return l
}
```

Output

```
VALUE :  7
Adding New Entry 7
VALUE :  5
Adding New Entry 5
VALUE :  4
Adding New Entry 4
VALUE :  5
Deleting  5
VALUE :  6
Adding New Entry 6
VALUE :  7
Deleting  7
VALUE :  5
Deleting  5
VALUE :  4
Deleting  4
VALUE :  9
Adding New Entry 9
7
5
4
6
9
```